# Plotly: Change hover popup styling

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(txhousing, x = ~date, y = ~median) %>% add_lines()
```

[image]

I would like to change the style of the hover pop-ups. The default style is just downright ugly. I would like to make it look more like highchart style.

[image]

The aim is to add text styling, increase padding around the text and restrict colour to the border. I can write the css style myself, but I would like to know how/where to inject it into. Where to define and load the style? What are the classes etc. I can't seem to get very far using `Chrome>Inspect`. I am using plotly in R.

Answer (score 2):

According to: https://plot.ly/r/reference/#box-hoverlabel-bordercolorsrc

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
gg <- plot_ly(txhousing, x = ~date, y = ~median) %>% 
add_lines()
style(gg, hoverlabel = list(bgcolor = "grey", bordercolor = "black", bordercolorsrc = "purple", font = "Arial"))
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a good start. But, it doesn't give me all the control I need.